# Symfony2 + FosUserBundle with "remember me" gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, remember-me

I am developing a website and noticed that the 'remember me' login functionality was not working.

So I added a remember me section to the security.yml

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
            provider: fos_userbundle
        remember_me:
            key:      "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000
            path:     /
            domain:   ~
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        anonymous: ~
```

For reference here is the access control section:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/account, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

The remember me functionality now seems to work because if I log in then close the browser and reload the browser I am still logged into the site. However if I try and go to any page that requires a user to be logged in (such as /account/settings) I get the following error:

```
The controller must return a response (false given).
500 Internal Server Error - LogicException
```

I have cleared the cache and that does not solve the problem.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: yeah, why down vote? just upvote to make it even. :)

Comment: I asked the obvious question.. are you sure that the controller that corresponds to the route `/account/settings` returns a result? Because the error is clear..

Comment: Yes, if I remove the 'remember_me' section from the firewalls settings in Security.yml all pages work perfectly.

Comment: Please add code of `/account/settings` controller to question. Possible that you have condition in conroller which depends on user role

Comment: The issues seems pretty clear.. your controller doesn't return a `Response` instance. Please provide the controller ocde

Answer (score 0):

somewhere in your code ( /account/settings  Action in the controller ) you have something like

```
return false;
```

or

```
$aVariable = false;
[... code ...]
return $aVariable;
```

debug your action ( /account/settings ) and make sure you return:
- an array if you're using annotations
or
- a "Response" instance if you`re using other method of defining routes

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer was very simple.

In my controller methods for any authenticated method I had:

```
$this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')
```

This needed to be changed to:

```
$this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')
```

That's it. Thanks goes to forgottenbas for helping me to figure this out.